# I want to know how to perform quantization-aware training for deeplab-v3+

Tags: tensorflow, quantization, deeplab

I have been trying to perform quantization aware training for deeplab using the guide given in this link
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize
However, I am not sure where exactly to put the below 2 lines that are required to activate the quantization

g = tf.get_default_graph()
tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(input_graph=g,quant_delay=2000000)

Where exactly in the deeplab train.py file do I put the above two lines?
I already tried on line 355, which is right after computing the loss and just before the optimizer initialization, as mentioned in the guide, but it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you find answer to this? I think this statement should go before all the 'def' are declared

Comment: Looks like they have an implementation here now https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/quantize.md