# Quantization aware training examples?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to do quantization-aware training with a basic convolutional neural network that I define directly in tensorflow (I don't want to use other API's such as Keras). The only ressource that I am aware of is the readme here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize

However its not clear exactly where the different quantization commands should go in the overall process of training and then freezing the graph for actual inference.

Therefore I am wondering if there is any code example out there that shows how to define, train, and freeze a simple convolutional neural network with quantization aware training in tensorflow?

It seems that others have had the same question as well, see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731996/i-want-to-know-how-to-perform-quantization-aware-training-for-deeplab-v3).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find/create a working example? I think this would be more than useful and the corresponding README.md for quantization could be updated afterwards.